# Can I black list other players?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a way to put someone in a black list, so they can't play with you again ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to ignoring the person, you could report them for "Unskilled Player".  Unskilled player reports never go to the tribunal or result in a ban, but are only used for determining matchmaking [[1](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=18796796#18796796)].

This will not result in a blacklist, but will help to minimize the chance of them being randomly queued with you.

Comment: I Correct the link @Toast Your made the best answer possible for this question. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

No there is no such thing in league of legends. But there is a report button.

Answer (score 1):

There is the ignore list, but that only prevents people from talking with you as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way so that you can never play with you again. However, the ignore list allows you to not see their pings and chat. But most forums I read concluded that it isn't a very refined nor foolproof method for doing so.